# Using sshpass with rsync to accept a fingerprint

Tags: rsync, sshpass

I'm using rsync to copy a file to a device:

```
sshpass -p <password> rsync -avzP <file> <user>@<IP address>:<folder>
```

This has worked fine in the past but I was trying to copy to a new device and got:

```
Host key verification failed.
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at rsync.c(703) [sender=3.2.3]
```

I removed `sshpass` and just tried `rsync -avzP <file> <user>@<IP address>:<folder>` and got:

```
The authenticity of host '<IP address>' can't be established.
<Name> key fingerprint is SHA256:<hex>.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

Entering `yes` fixes this, then I can run the original command. But how can I do this in a single command with `sshpass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `StrictHostKeyChecking` is set to `accept-new` or `no`, new hosts are automatically added to the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. The default is to `ask`.

If a host key changes, you will get a warning message that begins like this

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
```

and the connection is permitted if set to `no`. With `accept-new`, changed host keys are not permitted and you would have to remove the offending lines in `known_hosts` first.

```
sshpass -p <password> rsync -avzP -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new' <file> <user>@<IP address>:<folder>
```

If you want to override the default setting for all hosts, you could add an entry in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking accept-new
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `known_hosts` file located in this path `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

You can use the `"-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"` option to bypass the host key verification prompt and automatically add the new host key to the `known_hosts` file. The updated command would look like:

```
sshpass -p <password> rsync -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -avzP <file> <user>@<IP address>:<folder>
```